# Cmake windows project using Qt appears as windows 95

Tags: windows, user-interface, cmake, qt5, appearance

I am trying to build an apllication using CMake and Qt that does a bunch of stuff. All the logic is working fine so far, CMake is finding Qt 5.10.0 and the software runs, no struggle there. The window class is inheriting QWidget.

The problem I am having is that the appearence of the gui is like windows 95, where I want it to be modern windows 10-like

[image]

Does anyone have a fix for this, using cmake?

Comment: use `a.setStyle("fusion")`,  where `a` is QApplication.

Comment: @eyllanesc That should probably be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: It should indeed be the answer ;) works like a charm

Comment: Qt applications should look native straight out of the box, and setting the application style to fusion (which is a custom style) isn't really a solution. What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I am using Qt5.10.0, and i installed Qt using their online installer. I did not build it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eyllanesc mentioned setting the QApplication style to "fusion" did the trick. Does not look like windows now, but at least not the ugly windows 95 style.